# Where is Spring Boot Tomcat installation?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

After running Spring Boot Application, Tomcat require me to type admin password and login but I don't recall saving any. I have one Tomcat 8 installation on my system, where i made some changes in users.xml, added admin role and set password but it's not working in case when Boot app is being run.

Comment: It uses an embedded tomcat: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-tomcat

Comment: Have you read the Spring Boot documentation? My guess is that you have Spring Security on your class path and then spring security is automatically configured with a default user and generated password (as explained in the reference guide).